# 64x R in linux cluster with 200Gb: plyr package not enough to join tables

Tags: r, memory, bigdata, plyr, join

I'm running into an issue trying to join multiple data.frames using the `plyr` package in **R**.

Perhaps this is not the best tool/language for **joining tables** for **large datasets**? If anyone can suggest alternatives it would be greatly appreciated (e.g. alternative R packages, unix, or maybe MapReduce/Hadoop or python [NOTE: I have no python or mapreduce/hadoop experience].

I'm running a 64x bit version of R on a linux cluster which has up to 200Gb of available memory.

I have 22 samples/data.frames that each have 2-columns (**"ensembl_gene_id"** and **"FPKM"** values) with ~60,000 rows that I need to merge together. So the desired data.frame will have one column of **ensembl_gene_id** and then 22 columns of **FPKM** values.

In some samples there are genes missing so I cannot simply sort the data frames and join them line-by-line. So, my idea was to use the **plyr** package's **join()** function in an iterative fashion; however, I'm now questioning whether this is the ideal way to go about solving this problem due to the memory required.

I've provided 3 data.frames and the code I've tried.
[df1](https://gist.github.com/moldach/44b4240699b53099183b99af22f10648),
[df2](https://gist.github.com/moldach/ae374a50106074bdd2100673f43d268d), and df3 (I'm not reputable enough to post more than two links so I'm going to put it in the comment below)

```
library(plyr)

df1 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_1.csv")
df2 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_2.csv")
df3 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_6h_1.csv")

HAP1 <- join(df1, df2, by="ensembl_gene_name")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.5 Gb
```

The point about the failing to allocate vector is to highlight two points:

1) R give's very confusing errors. If I open another terminal window and check what R is actually using with the `top` command I could see that I was exceeding the default 8Gb I had access to! Therefore, I used `salloc` to request 80 Gb and tried the code below.
2) The second point is to demonstrate how the memory requirements swell as I do the **plyr** **join()** command in an iterative fashion.

```
HAP2 <- join(HAP1, df3, by="ensembl_gene_name")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 34282.1 Gb
```

Theoretically, even if I had access to Tb's of memory by the time I do more joins I think this vector would increase to make this problem non-tractable. For example,

```
HAP3<-join(HAP2, df4, by="ensembl_gene_id")
HAP4<-join(HAP3, df5, by="ensembl_gene_id")
etc.
```

Can anyone suggest what I should try next?

I noticed there a lot of genes without ensembl id's (~20,000 **NA**'s) in each data.frame. These are essentially meaningless so if I removed them prior to joining that may help. Another thing I though of was using the garbage cleaning function `gc()` in-between `plyr` joins. However, I'm still skeptical if this will help.

##########################WORKING UPDATE

Since this problem was solved by friendly users and I only put minimal code in the original question I thought I would write my workflow to help others in the future

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Load CSV files
df1 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_1.csv")
df2 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_2.csv")
df3 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_6h_1.csv")
df4 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_6h_2.csv")
...
df28 <- read.csv("HAP1_DMSO_6h_2.csv")

# Select only gene column and FPKM columns 
df1 <- select(df1,ensembl_gene_name,FPKM)
...

# Rename FPKM column to something meaningful (i.e. sample name) and omit NA's
df1 <- plyr::rename(df1,c("FPKM"="HAP1_dBet6_1h_1.csv"))
df1 <- na.omit(df1)
...

# Select unique gene name values and summarize FPKM counts
df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(ensembl_gene_name) %>% summarise(sum(K562_dBet6_1h_1))
...

df1 <- data.table(df1) # Turn data.frame into a data.table
setkey(df1, "ensembl_gene_name") # setkey() sorts a data.table and marks it as sorted
...

# Join data.tables
HAP1 <- merge(df1, df2, "ensembl_gene_name")
HAP2 <- merge(HAP1, df3, "ensembl_gene_name")
HAP3 <- merge(HAP2, df4, "ensembl_gene_name")
...
HAP27 <- merge(HAP26, df28, "ensembl_gene_name")
```

Thanks!

Comment: df3 link https://gist.github.com/moldach/6d238adcad538269f4fe658f81bf4865

Comment: I wonder whether you could try dplyr instead of plyr. It's supposed to be faster etc. But otherwise, I'd go for data.table (although it requires getting used to the different/new syntax).

Comment: i'll have a go at it later tonight, but so far, my gut feeling is that even dplyr falls over.

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach Matt, did anything work for you?

Comment: I also tried the `plyr` packages **join_all()** function for all three data.frames but no luck. Going to try `dplyr` and `data.table` next

Comment: Something is off here. 60k rows is actually not an awfully big data set. I'm wondering if `ensembl_gene_id` in every data file are unique? (there are no duplicate entries). Perhaps you want to aggregate first, if it's possible? Then do the join by ignoring NA's?

Answer (score 1):

Can you test this `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread("HAP1_dBet6_1h_1.csv")
df2 <- fread("HAP1_dBet6_1h_2.csv")
setkey(df1, "ensembl_gene_name")
setkey(df2, "ensembl_gene_name")
HAP1 <- merge(df1, df2, "ensembl_gene_name")
```

When dealing with larger data sets I prefer `data.table` objects with a `setkey` option.

**Edit:**

If `fread` is converting your gene names to something else, then you can use this:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_1.csv")
df2 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_2.csv")
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setkey(df1, "ensembl_gene_name")
setkey(df2, "ensembl_gene_name")
HAP1 <- merge(df1, df2, "ensembl_gene_name")
```

Comment: When I input the above code and than save HAP1 by `write.csv(HAP1, "HAP1.csv")` and open to look at it some of the gene names have been converted to dates. I can confirm this via `head(HAP1)` and then looking in df1 and df2 to make sure they are not there before.

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach Really? And genes in your csv files aren't converted to date? Because this is very common excel problem: https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-1044-7

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach Still.... You should testing joining, conversion (if it's data.table problem is solvable)

Comment: Whoops ok I checked the original file and it turns out these dates as gene names were a product of cuffdiff so it's not the above code. Sorry

Comment: @MatthewJ.Oldach happens, It's a well known excel problem, I haven't heard about R doing that

Comment: @PoGibas when I run your code, I get the data.table complaint about the cartesian join. Did that happen to you too? `length(intersect(df1$ensembl_gene_name, df2$ensembl_gene_name))` gives 38k matches, but that also implies more than 20k things that need resolution. Ie., the duplicate key-values create havoc.

Comment: So you need to add `allow.cartesian = TRUE` to the `data.table::merge()` and, given sufficient memory, things should go ok (but may still last a while).

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely consider removing `NA`s from your data.frame. You're likely duplicating each `NA` * the number of `NA` in your right-hand data.frame. Look at the output of `nrow(HAP1)` or `str(HAP1)`. Does it contain more many more rows than either `df1` or `df2`? A 60,000 x 22 data frame is not that large, but if your data frame expands after each join, it'll grow exponentially.

Comment: Yes I noticed the NA's and some duplicated gene names. So I remove them with:

`df1 <- read.csv("HAP1_dBet6_1h_1.csv")`
`df1<-unique(df1)`
`df1<-na.omit(df1)`

And the same for df2.

When I `nrow(HAP1)` there is still many more rows than either df1 or df2.

If I do the following:

`HAP1 <- na.omit(HAP1)` and do `nrow(HAP1)` again there's less than previously but still more than either df1 or df2. Not sure what to make of this result?

Comment: `df1 <- unique(df1)` will likely not return what you're expecting (a data frame of only unique ids). See if the `nrow(df1)` after subsetting is the same value as `unique(df1$ensembl_gene_id)`. To obtain a data frame with unique gene ids, you'll need to do something like `library(dplyr)` `uniquedf1 <- df1 %>% group_by(ensembl_gene_id) %>% summarise(sum(FPKM))`. And the same for df2. Then join.

Comment: Note that dplyr also has `dplyr::distinct(ensemble_gene_id)` that gives distinct rows based ony on gene id. I'm commenting here, because I only recently learned myself that dplyr's distinct enables this. Do add something like keep.others = T (check `?dplyr::distinct` for the exact name) to make sure that the other stuff remains.

Comment: @PaulLemmens thanks for the note. I didn't really think about `distinct` in this case but it's a useful verb to know. The issue with OP's data is that multiple gene ids may have different FPKM values that are meaningful. Some kind of aggregation is necessary for FPKM values in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much @CPak `uniquedf1 <- df1 %>% group_by(ensembl_gene_id) %>% summarise(sum(FPKM))` worked. 

This was all from an error with `unique()` not doing what I thought it was doing (leaving **duplicate key values** in each of the three data.frames as @PaulLemmens mentions below). 

This makes total sense as one would expect row numbers to be no more than df1 or df2. And as you join more data.frames the row number will likely decrease (or stay the same), never increase.

Comment: Happy to be of help. Best of luck with your analysis

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try things on your data, but I do have a suggestion.  Convert to matrices and use rbind.fill, possibly transposing the matrices before and after.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue/difficulty with the data is that both/all data frames contain duplicate key values (that data.table then also complains about saying it needs a cartesian product). So let's say df1 is something like

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
B 3
A 4
```

and df2 is

```
A 10
B 20
C 30
B 30
A 50
```

then the merge will become

```
A 1 ?
A 4 ?
A ? 10
A ? 50
# etc.
```

Where `?` is my representation for NA that R will put there. This is what data.table complains about (and note that the `by = .EACHI` that it suggests does not work because the `nrow(df1) != nrow(df2)`)

So you can do the maths how quickly this explodes with 66k rows having (i checked the three examples) approx. half of those duplicates. So you have to decide how to handle the duplicate keys. If the question marks in your end data frame are ok, then you can add `allow.cartesian = TRUE` to the `data.table::merge()` as suggested in my comment on PoGibas answer.

If you do worry about the `?`'s, then I think you could try and find the largest set of gene names that exist over all 22 files that you have and then manually loop over them and in this way constructing your final data frame. That will lose you data though.

Perhaps you could try and first concatenate all files into one long df (22 x 66k rows) with an additional column for the FPKM label and then using `tidyr::spread()` to spread it (possibly grouping by gene and doing the `spread()` in a `do()` loop for memory reasons)???

```
# pseudocode
myfiles <- as.data.frame(f = list.files(...))
hap <- myfiles %>% group_by(f) %>%
  do({
    d <- read.csv(.$f, ...)
    d$fpkm <- names(d)[2]
  }) %>%
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  do({
    d <- spread(., ...) #something with .$fpkm, and the other column
  })
```

There's probably a data.table way of doing this that's probably going to be faster.